# How to monitor STDOUT for a child_process spawn session that has a terminal animation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Let's say I want to run `npm install` inside a `node.js` and log the STDOUT. I could think of something like this:

```
var process = child_process.spawn("npm", ["install", package_name]);
process.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```

While this kind of execution works for some cases, in some cases it errors out. It's not giving me enough information what exactly is causing the error so I can only guess.

One thing I noticed is, nowadays a lot of `npm install` program executions do NOT display the log in a serial manner but instead display animation inline and stuff.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

My question is:

1. Might this kind of animation why the `stdout.on('data')` is erroring out in some cases?
2. How do I deal with this situation? I just want to get the full stream of all the data

Answer (score 0):

There is `stdout` and `stderr`. Maybe try to catch errors there? Here is part of my code where I use npm installer, but in a bit different way by utilizing `npm-cli.js`, which gives the option to use npm without its global installation on the server:

```
// Require child_process module
const { fork } = require('child_process');
// Working directory for subprocess of installer
const cwd = './path-where-to-run-npm-command'; 
// CLI path FROM cwd path! Pay attention
// here - path should be FROM your cwd directory
// to your locally installed npm module
const cli = '../node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js';
// NPM arguments to run with
// If your working directory already contains
// package.json file, then just install it!
const args = ['install']; // Or, i.e ['audit', 'fix']

// Run installer
const installer = fork(cli, args, {
  silent: true,
  cwd: cwd
});

// Monitor your installer STDOUT and STDERR
installer.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
installer.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

// Do something on installer exit
installer.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Installer process finished with code ${code}`);
});
```